# Including PHP, into a database - using php inside a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, include

Hello right now i have made it so, that every page i have is inside a database tabel the problem that occured to me now, is that i can not use PHP correctly since having php in a database does not function well. 
I tried doing some includes instead but i realized that it is not possible to use php in a database.

Any solutions? to connect some php to a page inside a database?

Comment: what do you mean by `some php to a page inside a database?`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In general it can't be what you want to store PHP (server code) in the database.

Comment: I made it so that, my pages are inside a mysql database. That is giving me trouble using php to like drag data out of the database into the page that is inside the database.

Comment: solution: dont store your php in the database

Comment: I'm trying to get some information out of the database, into the page in aspecific area in the page, that is inside the database.

Comment: Do you mean you have your HTML code inside the database?

Comment: @RichardBernards So you're saying it's not possible this way, i have to keep my site as a physical php file?

Comment: @Mrlitty yes my html code is inside the database.

Comment: It is possible... Everything is possible... But PHP and MySQL are not designed to be used in that fashion and it is considered to be 'REALLY BAD PRACTICE' to do this. Please read a starters tutorial in using PHP, MySQL and HTML and try taking it from there...

Comment: Isn't your question then: How to get the HTML code from the database using PHP code?

Comment: @Mrlitty, I already made it work, my site is dragging the html code from the database to the site. I made it possible to post feedback on my site via a form and paste it into the database, and i wanted to display the feedback on the html site that is inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing php code in a database is not a good idea beacause of many difficulties and risks (debugging, necessity to use eval function to run your code...). 
Store some HTML with precautions, but forget the idea of storing PHP code.
You should think about another way of organizing your code, maybe using MVC for example.

If necessary use eval() to run your code but at your own risks.

Comment: in fact, and you will lose in performance of PHP, and for reuse of your code etc etc..

Comment: Let me explain agien, All my pages build in HTML5 are on a database, i made a form so people could post feedback on the site, the feedback is saved in the database. So the thing i wanted to do so was to display the feedback people wrote. on this HTML side that is inside the database.

Comment: so If I understand there's no PHP code in the database, only the feedback (text or html) ? is this right ?

Comment: There's no php inside the database, There's this HTML site inside the database i build and i made a box for feedback to display. But i need to figure out how to get the feedback over to the HTML page. http://i.imgur.com/ZiWJ078.jpg

Comment: In fact there's PHP code in the database in your example. (your include dbconnect.php ).
This code is not in the right place. It should stay outside the database. You run yout dbconnect in the php file where you want to display the feedbacks

Comment: If I leave a feedback on your website, and I write something like "<? echo $password; ?> in my feedback, then I can access your password, etc.

Comment: @athax you can store onlly `php file name in database` and call that php filename where ever u want to display via iframe.. so it mean you can store directly into database instead of code

Comment: Ahh i oversaw that one, alright so how would i be able to include my feedback to my HTML side that is inside the database?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi could you explain yourself some more, i'm kind of new in all of this programming.

Comment: @athax first you need to create form page where you will upload your php files into the folder and store into database. once php file uploaded into the folder and filename stored into database then you can create function and mysql query and display your php code file in your website...